# The size of a family that contains one child of each gender.

Tags: probability

What is the likely size of a family that contains one child of each gender ?

This is a question from my textbook and the answer given is 3.

Here is a simulation.

I generated a series of random 0s (boys) and 1s (girls) on Excel.

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0

From each number I counted how many numbers until both number occurred.

1 0 (2)

0 0 0 1 (4)

0 0 1 (3)

0 1 (2)

1 0 (2)

etc

2 4 3 2 2 5 4 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 4

The average is 2.65

My question is how would you calculate the expected value ?

Comment: I think it must mean "_at least_ one child of each gender." Otherwise the answer is obviously $2$ (assuming that the parents aren't counted).

Comment: @TonyK In that case it's not possible to find an answer. The family has no reason to stop at a particular number of children. It's probable that it means the family has kids until there is a boy as well as a girl.

Comment: It's not clear that "likely size" refers to the mean, rather than the mode.

Comment: Kantura, please can you give us the complete question, word for word (or a translation of it)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but suspect that to be calculated is the expected number of children in a family where Mom and Dad have decided to stop getting children as soon as boys and girls are present among their children.

If $X$ denotes the number then $X=1+Y$ where $Y$ has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p=\frac12$.

E.g. the first child is a boy and after that $Y$ is the number of trials needed to arrive at first success where "success" stands for the birth of a girl.

So then: $$\mathbb EX=1+\mathbb EY=1+\frac1{\frac12}=3$$

It is preassumed here that the probabilities of boy and girl are equal.

Comment: I think you forgot to add parents into family size, because I got 5

Comment: @Heroofmetal In the question it is stated that 3 was the anwer in the textbook. So I reckoned that only children count here. Of course the answer is 5 if also the parents count (and things like polygamie are excluded).

Answer (score 0):

This actually has a really nice solution!

So let's derive the answer first: The probability for a couple to have a child of each gender after giving birth to one baby is naturally $p_1=0$. Without loss of generality, assume the first child has gender 0. When a couple conceives their second child, it is with probability 0.5 of gender 0, and with probability 0.5 of gender 1, but only in the latter case do they have both a daughter and a son. I.e., the likelihood that they have a child of each gender after the second kid is born is $p_2=0.5$. Call the situation that the parents got a child of each gender after giving birth to $n$ children $E_n$. In order for a couple to be in situation $E_3$, they shall have never been in situation $E_1$ or $E_2$. The likelihood of this, i.e., that both of their first two youngsters are of gender 0, is naturally $(1-0)(1-0.5)=0.5$. That $E_3$ holds - that their third child is of gender 1 - has then probability 0.5. As a whole, the probability $p_3$ of $E_3$ is therefore: $$p_3=(1-0)(1-0.5)\cdot 0.5=\frac{1}{2^2}$$
This pattern clearly continuous and we have
$$p_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
for $n>1$ and $p_n=0$ for $n=1$. To check that this makes sense we can see if the sum $P$ of all the probabilities $p_n$ actually sums up to 1, as it should:
$$P=0+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+...\implies\frac{P}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+...$$
$$\implies\frac{P}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+...\implies\frac{P}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=P\implies P=1$$
So far so good! Now for the average number of kids $N$ of the couple after they have a child of each gender, we get
$$N=1\cdot p_1+2\cdot p_2+3\cdot p_3+4\cdot p_4+5\cdot p_5+...=1\cdot0+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{2^2}+\frac{4}{2^3}+\frac{5}{2^4}+\frac{6}{2^5}+...$$
$$\implies\frac{N+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+\frac{4}{2^4}+\frac{5}{2^5}+\frac{6}{2^6}+...$$
A classic. We can solve it with the following trick:
$$\frac{N+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1+1}{2^2}+\frac{1+2}{2^3}+\frac{1+3}{2^4}+\frac{1+4}{2^5}+\frac{1+5}{2^6}+...$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+...\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{2}{2^3}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\frac{4}{2^5}+\frac{5}{2^6}+...\right)$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+\frac{4}{2^4}+\frac{5}{2^5}+...\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{N+1}{2}$$
$$\implies 2N+2=2+N+1\implies N=3$$
I suspect that the mistakte in your computation, the reason 2.65 as an average is so far off 3, is that you counted from *each* number how many numbers until both numbers occur. This assumes that the number of boys couple 1 has affects the number of boys couple 2 has. When the first couple bears 3 boys until they get a girl, the second couple will have 2 boys until they get a girl and the third couple one boy and one girl. So let's see what happens if we interprate the sequence of random 1s and 0s as follows:
$$\underbrace{1\ 0}_{2}\underbrace{0\ 0\ 1}_{3}\underbrace{0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1}_{5}\underbrace{0\ 0\ 1}_{3}\underbrace{0\ 0\ 1}_{3}\underbrace{0\ 1}_{2}\underbrace{0\ 1}_{2}\underbrace{1\ 0\ 0}_{3}$$
$$\frac{2+3+5+3+3+2+2+3}{8}=\frac{23}{8}=2.875$$
Well, at least a bit better! With such a small sample, this is no contradiction for sure.